# How to open folder and place text files in dataframe and rename dataframe based on file name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

I am trying to open a folder which has multiple text files and put each file in its own dataframe and name each dataframe by the filename.

My code so far is recognizing the 5 files in the folder but is not putting the data in the files into dataframes based on their file names. could someone show me how to do this?

code:
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import pypyodbc

```
loc = 'D:/filepath to folder with files'
os.chdir(loc)
filelist = os.listdir()
#print (len((pd.concat([pd.read_csv(item, names=[item[:-4]]) for item in filelist],axis=1))))

data = []
path = loc
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:
    with open(f,'r') as myfile:
        data.append(myfile.read())

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df.shape)
```

thank you in advance

-edit- 
How the data in the files looks:

```
0010010000013   1   CITY OF HOUSTON     1.000
0010020000001   1   CURRENT OWNER       1.000
0010020000003   1   MILBY CHARLES FAMILY PTNSH      1.000
0010020000004   1   FEAGIN MICHAEL RYAN TRUST       1.000
0010020000013   1   BUFFALO BAYOU PARTNERSHIP       1.000
0010020000015   1   BUFFALO BAYOU PARTNERSHIP       1.000
0010020000016   1   USRP PAC LP SPAGHETTI WAREHOUSE 1.000
0010020000023   1   CITY OF HOUSTON     1.000
0010020000024   1   LUISA MILBY FEAGIN 2007 TRUST       1.000
0010030000001   1   BUFFALO BAYOU PARTNERSHIP       1.000
```

-edit-
Final answer

```
dfs = {os.path.basename(f): pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', header=None,encoding='cp037',error_bad_lines=False) for f in glob.glob('D:/TX/Houston_County/Real_acct_owner/*.txt')}
```

Comment: what is the structure of the txt files- how do you want them to be as dataframes. comma separated values?

Comment: The body of your `for` loop is too narrow. You need to put `data = []` and the dataframe instantiation into the loop.

Comment: @JBr I made an edit with how the data in the files is. I would like the data with not csv but just spaces. thank you once again

Comment: @jbndlr I tried putting the data = [ ] in the for loop but got error ""Dataframe constructor not properly called".

Comment: From your code, it seems as if you would want to produce a single DataFrame holding the entire data from all files at once, but from your question, I read that you want to obtain an individual DataFrame for each file (named by file names). Could you clarify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should create a dict where each key (= filename) holds the dataframe with the respective file's contents.

```
filedfs = {}
for f in files: filedfs[f] = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(loc, f))
```

Or, as a one-liner as proposed by @MaxU:

```
dfs = {os.path.basename(f): pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True, header=None) for f in glob.glob('c:/data/*.csv')}
```

Comment: here is a one-liner: `dfs = {os.path.basename(f): pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True, header=None) for f in glob.glob('c:/data/*.csv')}`

Comment: @MaxU just tried your one line and did print(len(dfs)) and it says zero.

Comment: @jbndlr I also tried your line but got the error "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 233, saw 2". not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: @RustyShackleford: These are propositions. You have to change them to adapt your local settings. For the one-liner of @MaxU, you would have to change the path and pattern in the `glob` call to match your path and file extension, for my approach you would have to add further options to `read_csv` (define delimiters and headers, etc.)

Comment: @RustyShackleford, try this: `dfs = {os.path.basename(f): pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', header=None) for f in glob.glob('/your/path/*.csv')}` if you have a TAB separated file

Comment: Wild guess: Change the `glob` call to use `txt` extensions: `glob.glob('D:/path/to/file/*.txt')`.

Comment: @MaxU I tried your line with for tab seperated file, but when i go to print dfs, it shows me an empty list {}. Could you tell if this a data issue or something else?

Comment: @jbndlr that worked! by changing to "txt". Plus I had to add some encoding features. final edit above!

Answer (score 0):

***input:***

```
0010010000013,1,CITY OF HOUSTON,1.000
0010020000001,1,CURRENT OWNER,1.000
```

***code:***

```
import os
import pandas

loc = 'folder/'

list_of_df = []

for f in os.listdir(loc):
    if f.endswith(".txt"):

        df = pandas.read_csv(loc+f, sep = ',', names = ['number', 'count', 'buyer', 'status'])
        list_of_df.append(df)

for df in list_of_df:
    print df
    print '--'
```

Comment: I believe it must be an issue with my data bc I am getting error "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 233, saw 2".

Comment: I agree - I tried `sep = '   '`, `sep = ' '`, `sep = '\t'`, nothing worked for parsing the data into columns. if getting the data as comma-separated is an option, this would be an easy task.